# How to keep a div stuck in the same spot while the rest of page is scrolled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

example: http://www.ehow.com/how_2196172_ping-mac-computer.html

As you can see the "helpful?" element is stuck in place even when you scroll the rest of the page. I'm not sure if this can be done with just css or needs js (preferably jQuery). How can this be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to fix the element position. Try something like this:

```
div#ID {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:10px;
    left:10px;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

That is using [`position: fixed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning) which positions an element with respect to the browser view port.